# Pre and Post function for each Function Call in Golang

Tags: go

I want to perform some common actions for each function. Before the function starts and just before function Ends.

```
func Command1Processor() error {
   preCheck()
   // Actual command1 logic
   postCheck()
}

func Command2Processor() error {
   preCheck()
   // Actual command2 logic
   postCheck()
}
```

Is there anything in GoLang which support this so that I just write only logic and pre/post function get called automatically.

Comment: You could accept a func in your method, do your logic first, `defer` some logic and call the function passed to your wrapping function, would that suffice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve this by using middleware pattern which is quite popular for HTTP handlers.

You need a common middleware function like

```
func withCheck(http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        preCheck()
        h.ServeHTTP(w, r)
        postCheck()
    })
}
```

Then, you can wire up your handlers by additionally wrapping them into `withCheck` middleware:

```
myHandler := newMyHandler()
http.Handle("/foo", withCheck(myHandler))
```

This way, `preCheck` and `postCheck` will be called before and after every handler call.

For command processors without arguments the example will look as following:

```
type CommandProcessor func()

func withCheck(cp CommandProcessor) CommandProcessor {
    return CommandProcessor(func() {
        preCheck()
        cp()
        postCheck()
    })
}

func CommandProcessor1() {
    // Actual logic
}

func main() {
    cp1 := withChecker(CommandProcessor1)
}
```

The advantage of this approach is that you can have multiple middlewares. This pattern is easily adaptable for any number of arguments and/or function results.

Answer (score 4):

Some of this can be automated using defer.

Write a function that executes the pre-check and returns a function that executes the post-check.

```
func check() func() {
   // do the pre-check
   return func() {
      // do the post-check
   }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
func Command2Processor() error {
   defer check()() // note the double ()().
   // Actual command2 logic
}
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/hln-2MCORfB).